# Run two functions at once in python class

Tags: python, function, class

I there a way to run both the functions at a time in class and render the output.
the output I want is `['good', 'none-second']` in the end without calling `Rodger.fun`.

```
new=[]
a=10
class Dog():
    def fun(self): 
        if a==10:
            new.append('good')
        else:
            new.append('none-first')
        return new
    def hi(self):
        if a==11:
            new.append('second-good')
        else:
            new.append('none-second')
        return new

Rodger = Dog()
Rodger.fun()
Rodger.hi()
```

Output:

```
['good', 'none-second']
```

Comment: Look at ```multithreading``` and the ```threading``` module.

Comment: So you want the return value of `fun` without calling it?

Comment: What about creating a function that calls `fun` and `hi`?

Comment: yes. Correct @a_guest

Comment: @Jai Why do you want to do that?

Comment: It just a random idea which I got whether we can actually to it or not. Since I was unable to find a way, thought of posting it to have a better mind help. @a_guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `fun()` and `hi()` when initializing the class:

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, new):
        self.new = new
        self.fun()
        self.hi()
    def fun(self): 
        if a==10:
            self.new.append('good')
        else:
            self.new.append('none-first')
    def hi(self):
        if a==11:
            self.new.append('second-good')
        else:
            self.new.append('none-second')

new=[]
a=10
Rodger = Dog(new)
print(Rodger.new)
```

Output:

```
['good', 'none-second']
```